# Django Models Select a car model based on Car Make

Tags: python, django

Somewhat new to Django and I'm trying to create a car listing site. I've already ran into problems with the models. I can't seem figure out how I can create a model where if you select a particular make (e.g. Dodge) then you can select a model related to that make (e.g. Charger, Challenger, Viper etc.) or if you selected McLaren you could select from the 720s, 765lt, Senna, P1 etc.

```
models.py 
class Make(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField('Make', max_length=150)

    class Meta:
       ordering = ['make']
       unique_together = ["make"]
       verbose_name_plural = "Manufacturers"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.make 

class CarModel(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(default=datetime.datetime.today().year)
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model = models.CharField('Model', max_length=150)
    trim = models.CharField('Trim', max_length=150, help_text='Trim level')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['make', 'model', 'trim', 'year']
        unique_together = ("year", "make", "model", "trim")
        verbose_name_plural = "Models"

    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.year} {self.make} {self.model} {self.trim}'

class CarListing(models.Model):
    content = models.FileField("Media")
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    make_model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['make_model']
        verbose_name_plural = "Car Listings"

    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.make_model.year} {self.make_model.make} 
                  {self.make_model.model} 
                  {self.make_model.trim} '
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `related_name` for backwards compatibility.

```py
class CarModel(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(default=datetime.datetime.today().year)
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="models") # Note the related name here
    model = models.CharField('Model', max_length=150)
    trim = models.CharField('Trim', max_length=150, help_text='Trim level')
```

Then when you have a related name, you can easily access it by calling `models` on an instance

```
make = Make.objects.get(make="Dodge")
print(make.models) # Viper, Charger, Challenger, etc.
```

Note: `make = Make.objects.get(make="Dodge")` this will fire you an error if there are multiple records with the same query.

So you have to do something like this:

`make = Make.objects.filter(make="Dodge")` # return list of records`

Comment: `make.models` will return a Queryset of the models, so you can do other things like `get`, `order_by`, and any other ORM method

Comment: `models` is a manager so I think it should be `print(make.models.all())`